# Изменение наклона, размера текста и цвета поэтапно

Tags: javascript, css, css3, html5

Я хочу узнать, можно ли изменить размер текста, наклон и цвет   поэтапно на одной строке, например:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я хочу, если это возможно, использовать только `CSS`. Любое другое решение, которое, по крайней мере, не заставляет меня помещать каждую букву в свой собственный промежуток, тоже приветствуется.

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/49107252/7394871

Answer (score 3):

Как насчет применения к тексту трансформации и градиента?

```css
body {
  perspective: 250px;
  perspective-origin: bottom;
}

div {
  font-size: 70px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, black,rgba(0,0,0,0.3),rgba(0,0,0,0.2));
  display: inline-block;
  background-clip: text;
  color: transparent;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  transform: rotateY(70deg);
  transform-origin: left;
}
```

```html
<div>
  Lorem Ipsum Lorem
</div>
```